# Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object (But it works)

Tags: php, api, curl

I get the following Warning: 
`Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object.`

I know what this error represents and know why i get it, but I do not know how to fix it because the code works like a charm, so maybe you guys can help me out?

I curl a url with the following CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS:
`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(json_encode($data)));`

The vardump of json_encode($data) =

`string(57) {"transporterCode":"TNT","trackAndTrace":"3SAOLD1234567"}"`

Hence the error (it is a string), however I am not allowed to change anything because then the API call will fail. Is there anything I can do (besides supress the error) to fix it?

/love

Grumpymuppet

Comment: `http_build_query([json_encode($data])`?

Comment: You should pass first parameter array try this curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

Comment: You would expect that to work yes Forge Web Design, however it does not accept it without the json_encode. This is the message: `The supplied body does not meet the required specifications. Please check the message structure for errors.`

Comment: How would that work Berto99 with twice opening ( and once closing )?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that has the same issue. For me it was a combination of the required post method (PUT) and the http_build_query() who was messing that up.

I ended up using:

> ```
>        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
>        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
> ```

And that fixed it.

Good luck <3